# Python3 Flask session not appearing to update

Tags: flask, python-3.6

I'm using code below to debug an issue where it doesn't appear my session variable is being updated properly.

```python
print(session)
session['review_status'] = 'Pending'
print('Session review_status is now: ' + session['review_status'])
print(session)
```

This is outputting the following:

```
<SecureCookieSession {'review_id': None, 'review_status': 'New'}>
Session review_status is now: Pending
<SecureCookieSession {'review_id': None, 'review_status': 'New'}>
```

I can't understand why the last print statement isn't reflecting that the review_status value should now be "Pending" and not "New".

The frontend is firing off about 5 ajax requests at once to this endpoint, but the first one should be changing the status to Pending, so by the time the other 4 return, it would be "Pending" for them.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this was being caused by the asynchronous calls from the frontend. While watching the debug output, it seems that several of the calls were "finishing" before the Flask session was actually reflecting the new value that was stored.

When I converted the ajax call to "async: false", I then got the expected behavior after the first call finished (the remainder were no longer "New", but rather in "Pending").

I am going to leave this fix in place for now, but would be interested in alternatives to this, and getting a better understanding of how Gunicorn/Flask handles multiple requests to the same endpoint concurrently with regard to the session (ie: does the session remain static until all calls are fulfilled type thing).